# Tried to change the type of a column, but Rails tries to drop the table instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to change the data type of a column of a table. I tried two different approaches:

```
def change
    remove_column :users, :permission_level
    add_column :users, :permission_level, :integer
end
```

And

```
def change
    change_column :users, :permission_level, :integer
end
```

However, in both cases I got this error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "users"
/home/prios/blog/db/migrate/20170719071633_change_column_permission_level_from_string_to_integer.rb:3:in `change'
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "users"
/home/prios/blog/db/migrate/20170719071633_change_column_permission_level_from_string_to_integer.rb:3:in `change'
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
/home/prios/blog/db/migrate/20170719071633_change_column_permission_level_from_string_to_integer.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

It seems that Rails is trying to drop the table instead of removing/changing the data type of one of its columns, something I don't want.

Further info: The column I'm trying to alter/delete doesn't have any foreign keys associated to it. It's a column I haven't used yet.

Comment: do you have relational dependencies? like `dependent: :destroy`?

Comment: I only have a couple foreign keys, but none of them are linked to the column I want to alter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support the remove_column migration method. From http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-alter-table/:

> SQLite does not support ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN statement.

Apparently it's a pretty convoluted process in SQLite where you rename the existing table, create a new table without the column you want removed, copy over all the date from the original table, and then drop the original table. I ran into this when I was first getting started, made the switch to Postgres and haven't looked back.

Comment: apparantly Rails omits the very first step in that diagram: "Disable FK checks". I wonder if thats an oversight or a necessity in some way.